# Frank Davenport plot forecast with ggplot2

Tags: r, plot, ggplot2, time-series

I am trying to replicate Davenport's time series plot with ggplot2. I copied the code from his blog and made the changes that I found from others questions here. The code follows,

```
set.seed(1234)  
y<-arima.sim(model=list(order=c(2,1,1),ar=c(0.5,.3),ma=0.3),n=144)
y<-ts(y,freq=12,start=c(2000,1))


yt<-window(y,end=2009.99)

yfit<-Arima(yt,order=c(1,0,1))

yfor<-forecast(yfit)


pd<-funggcast(y,yfor)


library(ggplot2)
library(scales)


p1a<-ggplot(data=pd,aes(x=date,y=observed)) 
p1a<-p1a+geom_line(col='red')

p1a<-p1a+geom_line(aes(y=fitted),col='blue')

p1a<-1a+geom_line(aes(y=forecast))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lo95,ymax=hi95),
alpha=.25)

p1a<-p1a+scale_x_date(name='',date_breaks='1 year',minor_breaks='1  month',labels=date_format("%b-%y"),expand=c(0,0))

p1a<-p1a+scale_y_continuous(name='Units of Y')

p1a<-p1a+opts(axis.text.x=theme_text(size=10),title='Arima Fit to Simulated Data\n (black=forecast, blue=fitted, red=data, shadow=95% conf. interval)')
p1a
```

Untill the line

```
p1a<-p1a+geom_line(aes(y=fitted),col='blue')
```

Everything is how it is supossed to be. But when I run the nextline, i.e.,

```
p1a<-p1a+geom_line(aes(y=forecast))+geom_ribbon(aes(ymin=lo95,ymax=hi95),alpha=.25)
p1a
```

The result follows,

[image: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8G9nOe-HLIjczk1VGFNLUYyUGM/view]

And if I continue to run the rest of the code I get "Error in strsplit(unitspec, " ") : non-character argument" for the code line

```
p1a<-p1a+scale_x_date(name='',date_breaks='1 year',minor_breaks='1    month',labels=date_format("%b-%y"),expand=c(0,0))
p1a
```

And finally R cannot find the "opts" function. So I would like to know if I am doing something wrong or how to fix it. Thanks in advance!

Comment: it unclear to me where your error pops up and what is wrong with the "result" you have posted (the image) and ``opts`` its deprecated in favor of ``theme()``

Comment: hrbrmstr, thank you for your response. The image should be similar to [link](http://static1.1.sqspcdn.com/static/f/709683/17250840/1332375898473/Blog_Forecastggplot.png?token=mqzHJ1bacVo5CIINxBIFZ29fTf8%3D) That is, with the forecast plotted and the confidence interval. The problem is that I cannot find the error in the code.